# Empty file when trying to save registry key to file in Python

Tags: python, regedit, winreg

I want to export registry key to file in Python 3.8 but I'm getting only empty file (0kb) with nothing in it. Obviously I'm starting the script by elevating privileges to admin otherwise I would get a permission error.

It goes like this:

```
if is_admin():

    klucz = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Printers', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    file = (r"C:\SRCnetwork.reg")
    winreg.SaveKey(klucz, file)
```

Any idea what I might be missing ?

Comment: What if `klucz = winreg.OpenKeyEx(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Printers")`?

Comment: Sorry same thing, empty file

Comment: Do you have anything under that key? Check with *Regedit*.

Comment: Why is `file` a tuple?

Comment: Just a comment. I also don't think you need admin rights, as long as you don't write certain registry entries, such as in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winreg.html#winreg.SaveKey), the file cannot exist upfront. So maybe that prevents it to be written though your code is now otherwise correct? ... P.S.: The file is in your code not given as a tuple (that would be `("name",)`), but the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: @CristiFati   Yes I have 149kb when I manually export this key from registry

Comment: @Dr.V Yes I'm deleting the file from that path after every test, and everything inside the brackets is there cause otherwise I'm getting syntax errors.